# Can't upload Geotagged Photo folder in QGIS via Photo2KMZ?

Tags: qgis, geotag, photo2shape

I can't upload geotagged photos folder in QGIS via photo2KMZ. It's showing 
error as follows

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

KeyError: 'DateTime' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yash/.qgis2/python/plugins/photo_to_kmz/photo_to_kmz.py", line 173, in run
    dt1,dt2=a['DateTime'].split()
KeyError: 'DateTime'


Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) [GCC 4.8.4] 
QGIS version: 2.14.12-Essen Essen, exported 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/yash/.qgis2/python
/home/yash/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/home/yash/.qgis2//python
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools
```

[image: Screen Shot of Error message]

Comment: Thnx @tinlyx for editing the post!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when photos are missing the date-time property: https://hub.qgis.org/projects/photo2kmz/issues

The developer suggests that you make sure your photos has a valid date-time property. If this is a camera issue, you should report it as a new issue in the plug-ins bugtracker on the link above.